# What is the best way to stop a Unicorn Server process from running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the best way to stop a Unicorn Server process from running? Whenever I try to stop it using `kill -p 90234` it does not work. It is most likely something I am doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Not programming. ServerFault.com maybe.

Comment: there are some good rake tasks on github that wrap the kill calls - https://gist.github.com/1246503/7fb148968b0195a55b488ae1572c1ded84e15795

Comment: Does it not stop or gets restarted instantly? If it's restarted then there is something like runit/upstart/monit/systemd is bringing it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Things There - In Terminal type "ps" and have a look for the Master Unicorn Process. Copy the PID of it and then type "kill −9 90234" (where 90234 is PID of master unicorn process). After that worker process should disappear itself.

Comment: `kill -9` is never a safe way to kill a running process. I suggest Rob Cameron answer below.

Comment: Voted down. Killing with -9 can cause heaps of issues, as Gewthen described. kill -QUIT is much, much safer (as per Rob Cameron's answer).

Answer (score 83):

Have a look at the [Unicorn SIGNALS page](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/SIGNALS.html). If the master is behaving correctly and you just want to turn it off, you should send a QUIT signal:

```
kill -QUIT 1234     # where 1234 is the real process id, of course
```

That gracefully stops all the workers, letting them finish any requests that they're in the middle of serving.

Comment: To kill the current process: `\`kill -QUIT #{Process.pid}\``

Answer (score 42):

I use this:

```
ps aux | grep 'unicorn' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo kill -9
```

I just looked back at this two months later. This is craziness, and don't use this if you have more than one Unicorn master and you only want to kill one of them.

Comment: This works great if you have a million hanging orphaned workers

Answer (score 19):

Interesting that no-one considered the pid file that unicorn creates? My usual config puts it in ./tmp/unicorn.pid, so perhaps the safest way is

```
kill -QUIT `cat tmp/unicorn.pid`
```

and the pid file is then properly deleted by the departing process. I always put the pid file in the same relative place so I guess I could alias that for convenience, although when I am developing I don't usually daemonize unicorn.

Comment: kill -QUIT `cat shared/pids/unicorn.pid` is another common location for the PID file

Comment: Can set the location of your pid file in development in /config/unicorn/development.rb with: `pid "tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"`. Then ```kill -QUIT `cat tmp/pids/unicorn.pid````

Answer (score 11):

I would probably go with:

```
sudo pkill unicorn_rails
```

Comment: I believe this is the best answer, I did sudo pkill unicorn though

Comment: This is no good if you have multiple unicorn servers running and you only want to end a specific one...

Answer (score 4):

```
ps aux | grep unicorn
#=> root   4393  2.0  0.9  65448 20764 ?  S  20:06   0:35 unicorn_rails m
kill 4393
```

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately, the key is the following line which targets the master unicorn process and kills it

```
kill $(ps aux | grep '[u]nicorn_rails master' | awk '{print $2}')
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually I'm lazy and I just kill by name:

```
$ killall processname
```

Answer (score 0):

for those using chef and seeing that none of the above works (because the processes are respawned as soon as you kill them):

`sudo sv stop APP_NAME`

`sv` is the control for `runit`.

Answer (score 0):

To quit a specific Unicorn server you can use something like the following:

```
pkill -QUIT --pidfile /path/to/app/shared/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
```

This way you can selectively kill any process and you don't have to use shell evaluation/expansion which may not be available.