# The production mode ruby app doesn't run, unicorn and nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx

I'm going to deploy my ruby on rails app on my own server. So i decided to follow this tutorial that is from degital ocean:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-unicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

I configured my database.yml which i add host:localhost and configured rben-var in my app directory and Migrate the production database very well.
I couldn't start the rails with this command 
RAILS_ENV=production rails server
And i thought maybe it is because of my last time that I set the unicorn as default for my another app(you know i have two other app which i deploy them on the server well but i removed their path from the nginx)
then I create config/unicorn.rb 
finally when I started 
sudo vi /etc/init.d/unicorn_drug it gives me  this error:

```
master failed to start, check stderr log for details
```

When i see the log which Is in /shared/log/unicorn.stderr.log i see following error lines.
You know i spend two days on this case but I really can't understand what is the error is:

```
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:752:in `call'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:752:in `build_app!'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:129:in `start'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/unicorn:23:in `<top (required)>'
I, [2017-02-27T13:38:21.860366 #1848]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
NameError: uninitialized constant RegistrationController
  /root/drug_api/app/controllers/RegistrationController/confirmations_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:150:in `exclusive'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:476:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `each'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `block in eager_load!'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `each'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `eager_load!'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:354:in `eager_load!'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:59:in `each'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:59:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
  /root/drug_api/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:4:in `require_relative'
  config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn.rb:56:in `eval'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn.rb:56:in `block in builder'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:752:in `call'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:752:in `build_app!'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:129:in `start'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/unicorn:23:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: Did you stop Unicorn in between? It may be running in the background. `ps ax | grep -i unicorn`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39702154/unicorn-stuck-in-loop-refreshing-gem-list

Comment: @Casper i run the command that u shared and get this output

Comment: 1092 ?        Sl     0:01 unicorn master -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D                                                                          
 1095 ?        Sl     0:00 unicorn worker[0] -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D                                                                       
 1098 ?        Sl     0:00 unicorn worker[1] -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D

Comment: @Casper shared here https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e29cd9eca6ab9109be7cb809e488dbd5

Comment: Look here how to stop a process, then try your app again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749963/what-is-the-best-way-to-stop-a-unicorn-server-process-from-running

Comment: @Casper i reboot the server

Comment: Ok. Hope it helps. In the future it's a good idea to learn how to kill a process. It's quite easy to do (use the `kill` command). Then you won't need to reboot every time. Just read the SO link I posted and you will be a master at killing processes.

Comment: @Casper i reboot the server and when i wanted to start unicorn i get the above error, in fact nothing changed after reboot

Comment: Ok. Then there's something else going on. Too little information to figure out what it is. You should post your config files and unicorn scripts also.

Comment: Also post this file:  /root/drug_api/app/controllers/RegistrationController/confirmations_controller.rb

Comment: @Casper this is my confirmation_conreollers code https://gist.github.com/anonymous/913e24aec8a83645b3f34e2b37891003

Comment: @Casper you mean the unicorn which is in config/unicorn.rb

Comment: Yes. `config/unicorn.rb`.

Comment: @Casper this is my unicorn https://gist.github.com/anonymous/db7087f2dd3186c12479d159babfef33

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136750/discussion-between-casper-and-androiddev).

Comment: My guess is that you have a syntax error in confirmations_controller.rb

Comment: @gates i remove confimations_controller.rb because it is empty and i don't use it anymore, by the way, it works on development mode but in production, it just sock

Answer (score 0):

The problem is uninitialized constant RegistrationController, your  RegistrationController is missing. Also seems that you have named directory to RegistrationController and under that you have placed confirmation_controller. Rename the directory to registration_controller, cause you can not name path or directory with first letter capital, that is only for class name.

Check line no. 8 of your error log:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant RegistrationController
  /root/drug_api/app/controllers/RegistrationController/confirmations_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```